# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable python3 but no round() or sum() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Currently trying to create a program that generates a number given user input amount of digits however, it will sometimes generate under the users digit choice. I created an if condition to check this but it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

***Here is my python3 code so far...***

```
    # To generate number with certain amount of digits by user input as a list:
import random as gen
digit_count = int(input('Enter number of digits: '))
def function():
    max = int('9' * digit_count)
    number = gen.randint(0, max)
    check = len(str(abs(number)))
    if check != digit_count:
        print(number)
        function()
    else:
        print(number)
        print(max)
function()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Can you provide the code which gives the error. Can you tell what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do not use max as an variable because it is an inbuilt function - `some_other_var = int('9' * digit_count)`

Comment: @PCM 1. It is a good practice. 2 But in this case it doesn't matter

Comment: It matters because when I changed it, it seemed to work. Only error was maximum recursion depth

Comment: @PCM doing that has actually appeared to fix my code. I don't know how that caused the issue but it certainly fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Hmm. So there was a piece of code which intended to use ```max()``` function but since ```max``` was a variable, it was not callable

Comment: If you look at what the parameters of randint do you might be able to simplify your problem

Comment: @paradocslover, when you assign a variable like this - `a = b()` then it becomes a variable for the function - `a()`. Here, the error was because it was assigned to max function to  do - `somenum()` or something.

Comment: Search for ```max``` in your code.

Comment: *then it becomes a variable for the function*? The function gets over ridden with the value assigned to the variable with the same name.